# Setting Google FireStore Permissions to avoid overwriting data

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-security, google-cloud-firestore

I have a project I am working on that takes data written by the following statement in swift 4:

```
@IBAction func saveButton(_ sender: Any) {
        db.collection("violets").document(plantName.text!).setData([
            "Plant Name": "\(plantName.text ?? "")",
            "Hybridizer": "\(hybridizer.text ?? "")",
            "Registration Number": Int("\(registrationNumber.text ?? "")"),
            "Type": "\(type.text ?? "")",
            "Description": "\(generalDescription.text ?? "")",
            "Notes": "\(notes.text ?? "")"
        ]) { err in
            if let err = err {
                print("Error writing document: \(err)")
            } else {
                print("Document successfully written!")
            }
        }

        uploadImage(violetImage.image!)

    }
```

This is written to my FireStore successfully:

[image: FireStore]

My problem is when adding more data, its easy to overwrite an existing document in FireStore. I think the best way to go about fixing this is to implement specific permissions to restrict overwriting data.

My hope was to try to only allow overwrite if a user is Authenticated and if the document name wasn't already present in the database.

This is my FireStore permission config:

```
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read : if request.auth.uid != null;
      //allow write: if request.auth.uid != null && !data.exists
    }

    match /violets/{violetID} {
            allow write: if !exists(violetID)

        }
  }
}
```

At this point is just denying all writing period. Am i misunderstanding the file structure of FireStore or is something else here wrong?

EDIT: Think I got closer but still no cigar...

Comment: Doesn't the `exists()` function require a full path? [As described here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/reference/security/#service_defined)

Comment: Im not sure to be honest. Im sure its a syntax issue. I just don't know where. Its either my match statement or the exist statement.

Answer (score 0):

So I was never actually able to get the permission validation itself to work; but I found a way to do it in code by validating that the document I was trying to write existed or not. Here was my final solution:

@IBAction func saveButton(_ sender: Any) {

```
let docRef = db.collection("violets").document(plantName.text!)
    docRef.getDocument { (document, err) in

        guard
            let document = document,
            let user = document.exists ? document : nil
            else {
                print("Plant does not exist in DB. Writting new Entry")
                        self.db.collection("violets").document(self.plantName.text!).setData([
                            "PlantName": "\(self.plantName.text ?? "")",
                            "Hybridizer": "\(self.hybridizer.text ?? "")",
                            "Registration Number": Int("\(self.registrationNumber.text ?? "")"),
                            "Type": "\(self.type.text ?? "")",
                            "Description": "\(self.generalDescription.text ?? "")",
                            "Notes": "\(self.notes.text ?? "")"
                                ]) { err in
                                    if let err = err {
                                        print("Error writing document: \(err)")
                                    } else {
                                        print("Document successfully written!")
                                    }
                                }

                        self.violetImage.image = self.violetImage.image?.resizeWithWidth(width: 120)
                        self.uploadImage(self.violetImage.image!)
                        self.itemFinishedAdding()
                return
        }

        print("\(self.plantName.text!) is already in the database")

}
```

}

While this logic works... I am not quite satisfied with it. Still Chuggin' at it.